# Pass parameter to a systemd-nspawn container

Tags: linux, containers, systemd

I'm trying to setup a CI to compile my packages using systemd-nspawn.

How can I pass the name of the package to the container ? I tried with the following command, but as the env is cleared after login (auto login using agetty), so I can't use it.

```
systemd-nspawn --setenv=PACKAGE=$1 -b -x -M exherbo-template --bind=[...]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the `Environment=` option in a `.nspawn` file, as described in `man 5 systemd.nspawn`.  In `man systemd-nspawn` a number of options are also provided to mount or overlay filesystems that become available to the container. You could write the package to file or path that is available to the container this way as well.

Comment: `Environment=` as the same effect than `--setenv=`, so it doesn't solve the problem. The file could be a good idea but not really efficient for a CI system with ephemeral containers.